# Como faço para manter a palavra iris-setosa como texto in python: df=pd.read_sql('SELECT class = 'iris-setosa' FROM tbl_iris',cnxn)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ipython-notebook

Olha o conexão já foi feita com sucesso no SQL Sever, já testei comandos como: df=pd.read_sql('SELECT class FROM tbl_iris',cnxn) ou até mesmo df = pd.read_sql('SELECT sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,class FROM tbl_iris WHERE sepal_width > 2.5',cnxn) e funcionam normalmente. o problema é sintaxe das ' ' para referenciar a palava iris-setosa. PS: o problema é as aspas poderia ser qualquer outra palavra no lugar de iris-setosa, neste caso qualquer palavra que estiver dentro  da coluna class

Comment: Por favor, seja mais claro com a descrição do seu problema e forneça mais informações para que a comunidade consiga ajudar. Recomendo que você leia estes tópicos do FAQ: 

[Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-completo-e-verific%C3%A1vel)


[Como se portar ao perguntar/responder?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/38/como-se-portar-ao-perguntar-responder)

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isso resolve:

`df=pd.read_sql("SELECT class = 'iris-setosa' FROM tbl_iris",cnxn)`

Observe que coloquei externamente aspas duplas.